# JPQL not running on the server

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a MySQL database. I'm using Spring Boot JPA and creating a query with JPQL.

```
@Query(value="SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c WHERE c.distributorId " +
            "IN (SELECT DISTINCT d.distributorId FROM Distributor d WHERE d.partnerId=?1)")
    List<Category> findDistinctByPartnerId(long partnerId);
```

It works fine and dandy, EXCEPT in the server (of course). The problem is, it starts the server (meaning, the Entity classes DO get loaded properly), but the query responds the following error:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) Table 'exampleDb.category' doesn't exist
```

I never added the database name to the Entities, and that doesn't even show in the debug sql:

```
Hibernate: select distinct category0_.CategoryId as Category1_5_, category0_.CatalogCode as CatalogC2_5_, category0_.CategoryName as Category3_5_, category0_.DistributorId as Distribu4_5_, category0_.ParentId as ParentId5_5_ from category categor
y0_ where category0_.DistributorId in (select distinct distributo1_.DistributorID from distributor distributo1_ where distributo1_.PartnerId=?)
```

I've been searching for a response to this, but to no avail. 
Thanks in advance for all your help!

Category Class:

```
@Entity
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Getter
@Table(name="category")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="CategoryId")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    String categoryId;
    @Column(name="CategoryName")
    String categoryName;
    @Column(name="CatalogCode")
    String catalogCode;
    @ManyToOne
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentId", referencedColumnName = "CategoryId")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Category parent;
//    @OneToOne
//    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "DistributorId", referencedColumnName = "DistributorId")
//    Distributor distributor;
    @Column(name="DistributorId")
    Long distributorId;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Category category = (Category) o;
        return categoryId.equals(category.categoryId) &&
                Objects.equals(categoryName, category.categoryName) &&
                Objects.equals(parent, category.parent) &&
                distributorId.equals(category.distributorId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(categoryId, categoryName, distributorId);
    }
}
```

Connection through JNDI:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/jdbc/mapper
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=mapper
```

Comment: Add your `Category` class too.

Comment: Add connection information

Comment: I think that *Table 'exampleDb.category' doesn't exist* is self explainatory.

Comment: When Spring boot starts, the first thing it does is to verify the tables, as well as the jndi connection. The model gets bound by start, so it's not self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, DB table doesn't exist, can you try inserting an entry in your application.properties like `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

Maybe, your DB doesn't have the table, and your application at the time of startup assumes the table exists within DB.

And, if that's not the case, then can you please share server start up time logs, will help in further debugging the cause of this behavior. Thanks!